# How to access active worksheet using nodejs and GAS?

Tags: node.js, google-apps-script, google-api

I am trying to get active worksheet from google spreadsheet, but I am not able to get current active worksheet.

Here is my calling script from nodejs:

```
function callAppsScript() {
  var scriptId = 'myscriptid'
  var script = google.script('v1');
  var auth = getOAuthClient();
  auth.setCredentials({
    client_id: 'myclientid',
    client_secret: 'mycs',
    refresh_token: 'myrt'
  });

  // Make the API request. The request object is included here as 'resource'.
  script.scripts.run({
      auth: auth,
      resource: {
        function: 'publicFunction',
        parameters: [spreadsheetid],
        devMode: true
      },
      scriptId: scriptId
    }, function(err, resp) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
        return;
      }
      var apiresp = resp.response.result;
      console.log('current sheet id : ', apiresp);
    }
  });
}
```

Here is my google apps script:

```
function publicFunction(params) {

  var id = SpreadsheetApp.openById(params).getSheetId();

  return id; // it is always returning first worksheet Id 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get active spreadsheet you can either use:

[getActive()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactive) or [getActiveSpreadsheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactivespreadsheet)

> "Returns the currently active spreadsheet, or null if there is none.
>   Functions that are run in the context of a spreadsheet can get a
>   reference to the corresponding Spreadsheet object by calling this
>   function."

Comment: but these methods works when the script is related to particular spreadsheet. Here i am sending spreadsheet id of different spreadsheet, means script is common for other spreadsheet id also.